# Custom camera not working on 4.0.4

Tags: android, android-camera

I test this code in android 2.2 and android 3.2. its working perfect but when i run in android 4.0.4, its not working. when i click on button for take picture, application not responding and going hang.

Preview.java

```
package com.example;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;


class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "Preview";

    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    public Camera camera;

    Preview(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        camera = Camera.open();
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);


            camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                    try {
                        outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));    
                        outStream.write(data);
                        outStream.close();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                    }
                        Preview.this.invalidate();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
        // important to release it when the activity is paused.
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera = null;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
//        parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.draw(canvas);
            Paint p= new Paint(Color.RED);
            Log.d(TAG,"draw");
            canvas.drawText("PREVIEW", canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2, p );
    }
}
```

CameraDemo.java

```
package com.example;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class CameraDemo extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraDemo";
    Camera camera;
    Preview preview;
    Button buttonClick;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        preview = new Preview(this);
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);

        buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
        buttonClick.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
            }
        });

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate'd");
    }


    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
        }
    };

    /** Handles data for raw picture */
    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
        }
    };

    /** Handles data for jpeg picture */
    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            long time = 0;
            try {
                // write to local sandbox file system
//                outStream = CameraDemo.this.openFileOutput(String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()), 0);    
                // Or write to sdcard
                time =  System.currentTimeMillis();
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg",time));    
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {



            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
        }
    };

}
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layout">
 <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Camera Demo"
  android:textSize="24sp" />

 <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/preview"
  android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 </FrameLayout>

 <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
  android:text="Click" android:layout_gravity="center"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you saying this happens in emulator?

Comment: @Dibya no, i tested in devices..

Comment: @ZouZou as i said there is no error i found.. its just not responding.. nothing display in logcat.

Comment: This code works for me on 2.3.6 Samsung Galaxy S and 4.0.4 Samsung Galaxy S Duos. You need to explore your issue a little bit more for anyone to help you.

Comment: @Marko i tried in samsung tab 2. still not working.

Comment: Wait are you trying to record every frame in JPG format on SD card? This code is probably creating a bottle neck in some place, and newer versions are never happy when you do a lot of work on UI thread. Find this part and you'll find your issue

Comment: It Happened some times from problem in particular devices did you tray it on another device has 4.0.4 version ??

Comment: no, only in one device i checked.

Comment: try to make emulator with 4.0.4 version if it works try to test it on another device if not 
please print the Logcat maybe we can help you

Comment: but camera not work in emulator i think so..

Comment: @SagarMaiyad: Have a look at `https://github.com/dawidgatti/dgCam`,let me know if it works for you,I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use this line "/sdcard".
Dont hard code it in code instead use a neat approach by calling Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() method.
I think this might be the problem.
Please check and confirm.